# What is the best way for store images of website?

Tags: performance, storage, image, cassandra, big-data

We are using cassandra database for store website information, but we are not sure how to save images.

We can store them in cassandra, but we can also allocate a server for storing images.

Cassandra has  good performance for big-data storage but if we store images in cassandra we must save them as bytes. For any retreival, first we must read image-bytes from cassandra and store it in a folder and then send it's address to the web page.

Do you have any ideas for this problem?

Comment: What did you end up doing? did you store them on database or file system?

Comment: As far as I remember, we stored thumbnails in database and original photoes in file system.

Comment: I'm considering storing them on Cassandra, but the concept of nosql is very new to me. It has a learning curve

Comment: Walmart did this in Cassandra at very large scale: https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/building-object-store-storing-images-in-cassandra-walmart-scale-a6b9c02af593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was a bit hard to understand, but in the end I think you mean to serve images, and are figuring out if you want to do either

- save them in cassandra, and on retreival write them to a file, and send the link to the client.
- save them on a separate server.

The first doesn't make too much sense to me: if you read them from cassandra, you can probably just stream them to the client without saving them first. But even in that case, I'd go for a file-system sollution: if you have no other demands then just to save the files and serve them you should use file-system.

Comment: Our website has a large amount of data! maybe we need to store several billions images! if we store these images in one server with file-system i think this server maybe can't response all requests! but cassandra has a good strategy for read and write data when we have a large amount of data. And it can divide all data between several servers and manage their's with a high performane. But i'm not sure yet! I need more information! can every one guide me?

Answer (score 9):

No.

Just No.

You don't store images in a database.

Images are files.

[Do not store files in a database.](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/not-storing-files-database/#.UeVXKI3vuW0) (Source: My blog post, I wrote in 2012)

Databases are for storing data.

Filesystems are for storing files.

Store files in a filesystem.

Comment: You need to mention that link is to *your* blog/website...

Comment: I see your link ([Do not store files in a database.](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/not-storing-files-database/#.UeVXKI3vuW0))! this article is about sql databases but cassandra is a no-sql database! In this article was written: "I'm also primarily talking about RDBMS type databases, not NoSQL, which tend to have a mechanism for storing files a little bit more sanely than "old-fashioned" databases."

Comment: SQL or NoSQL, my point stands, you'll still have to convert between database stream storage and a file ready to be served.

Comment: How do you solve the replication problem? All files should be replicated with no single point of failure. So you still need some distributed filesystem or Key-Value store specialized for files. What do you suggest here?

Comment: A distributed file system,  naturally.  Ceph,  gluster,  plain old xfs and rsync,  drdb, Amazon S3, there's so many to choose from.

Comment: Walmart stored 100s of millions of images in Cassandra: https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/building-object-store-storing-images-in-cassandra-walmart-scale-a6b9c02af593

Comment: OP isn't Walmart tho.